# when I read excel sheet First row getting as Header

Tags: c#

[image: Excel sheet like this]

My excel sheet does not  have headers. When I read this excel, first
row getting as Header like this How can I solve this issue.

[image: this is the Datatable]

I'm reading the excel like this

```
OleDbConnection conn1;
conn1 = new OleDbConnection();
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter;
conn1.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtFileName.Text + ";
Extended Properties=\'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\'";
conn1.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", conn1);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

dataAdapter.Fill(ds);

dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

Comment: HDR=NO in connection string

Answer (score 2):

You have specified headers in connection string `HDR=YES` change it to `HDR=NO`

Comment: Thank you very much, Highly Appreciate your reply. I fixed the issue.